# Color coded 'ls' under ssh connection from Mac to SunOS server (tcsh shell)

Tags: shell, solaris, tcsh

I'm on a Mac under OSX. I ssh into a remote server which is running SunOS. The default shell under the remote server is `tcsh`, not `bash`. How can I set the `ls` to generate color coded output as I have under the bash shell in OSX.

I can get a color coded custom prompt by editing the `.cshrc` file to include something like:

```
set prompt="%{\033[1;31m%}%n%{\033[1;34m%@%m %{\033[0;37m%}%~ %{\033[1;36m%}%%%{\033[0m%} "
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to edit the directory listing colors. It it even possible to do so?

I should state up front that I do not have admin access to this server, so I can't blanket install the gnu alternatives  (or at least, I would have to set them up locally, which I don't yet know how to do.)

Comment: Not sure for SunOS. On CentOS in tcsh the colors are provided by the environment variable LS_COLORS, better said ls is using the variable. Can you check this on SunOS?

Comment: Usually the `ls-F` builtin (no space!) should do this, but I haven't used Solaris in years so I can't test/be sure. You can try looking for a flag in `man ls` (maybe `--color` or `-G`?) Many default bashrc files alias `ls` to something with colours...

Comment: LS_COLORS is undefined. I tried defining it, but no dice. However, I'm not very good at this, so I may be doing something wrong.

--color isn't a valid flag under this install.

Comment: What version of Solaris?  `ls` may have a `-colors` option.  Do you have a `/usr/gnu/bin` directory?  Does the install have GNU utilities in the default path - `ggrep`, `gtar`, etc.?  One thing to be aware of - GNU utilities can't handle Solaris-specific features such as a file's extended attributes.

Comment: It's Solaris 5.10. There's no gnu directory in `/usr/`, though the gnu utilities `ggrep`, `gtar` exist and are located under `/usr/swf/bin`. Gnu emacs is in `/usr/local/bin` (by default, I didn't install it there.) Can I grab a Solaris `gnu ls` binary and dump it there?

Comment: Sorry, it's SunOS 5.10, which I guess means its Solaris 10.

Comment: @WildGunman Is there a `gls` in `/usr/sfw/bin`?  That would be GNU `ls`.

Comment: @andrew-henle No, there's not. Sorry, I should have specified, I looked for `gls`.